# BluePrism Data Type getting set to Unknown

Tags: blueprism

We have a BluePrism process that uses a username and password for the input to login to a system. However, after spying the elements, one value is always getting set to an Unknown data type. Has anyone seen this before? Interestingly enough, if I move the password field to the top of the list, then that becomes Unknown and Username correctly goes to Text. Whatever element is on the top of the action list, defaults to Unknown.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Here is a partial answer, I hope (therefore as comment). 
For Read Action: The type changes to the correct one if you select  in the Data column dropdown the Data you want to read, i.e. "Get Current Value" (Text) or "Get Screen Bounds" (Collection) etc. This make sense, because the data you want to get determines what type you get.
For Write Actions: I never seen something else as "Unknown" in the Type column. However, I don't see the reason, why.